# Delete Records Except Last Three Records

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete, records

I have a `log` table in which I want to delete records of each user except last three records.

**Schema**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `log`;
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `log`(`user_id`,`timestamp`) values (1,1389257013),(1,1389257014),(1,1389257015),(1,1389257016),(1,1389257017),(2,1389257018),(2,1389257019),(2,1389257020),(2,1389257021),(2,1389257022),(3,1389257023),(3,1389257024);
```

**Current Table:**

```
id    timestamp
1     1389257013
1     1389257014
1     1389257015
1     1389257016
1     1389257017
2     1389257018
2     1389257019
2     1389257020
2     1389257021
2     1389257022
3     1389257023
3     1389257024
```

**Expected Table**

```
id    timestamp    
1     1389257015
1     1389257016
1     1389257017
2     1389257020
2     1389257021
2     1389257022
3     1389257023
3     1389257024
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below SQL:

```
DELETE FROM log WHERE find_in_set(
    TIMESTAMP, (
        SELECT group_concat(t3) t4 FROM (
            SELECT 1 AS dummy,
            replace(group_concat(TIMESTAMP ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC), concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(TIMESTAMP ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC), ',', 3), ','), '') t3
            FROM log
            GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*) > 3
        ) a GROUP BY dummy
    )
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06541/3)

Comment: Much better !! This is bit shorter than previous solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
DELETE l FROM `log` l 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM (SELECT l.user_id, l.timestamp, 
                       IF(@lastUserId = @lastUserId:=user_id, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=0) rowNumber 
                FROM `log` l, (SELECT @lastUserId:=0, @Idx:=0) A
                ORDER BY l.user_id, l.timestamp DESC
               ) AS A
          WHERE l.user_id= A.user_idAND l.timestamp = A.timestamp AND rowNumber < 3
         );
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/615c83/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| USER_ID |  TIMESTAMP |
|---------|------------|
|       1 | 1389257015 |
|       1 | 1389257016 |
|       1 | 1389257017 |
|       2 | 1389257020 |
|       2 | 1389257021 |
|       2 | 1389257022 |
|       3 | 1389257023 |
|       3 | 1389257024 |
```

Comment: Can a query be written for same problem in which MAX(`timestamp`) is found three times with user_id less than last record of same user?

Comment: @neeraj Inner query will generate userwise unique row numbers.

Comment: Ok, Did you see my second comment regarding usage of MAX aggregate function instead of rownumber?

Comment: @neeraj MAX will return latest data only. You can't find latest 3 records

Comment: Another Solution :: DELETE FROM `log`
where  `timestamp` IN 
(
 SELECT `timestamp` FROM
 (
  SELECT `user_id`, `timestamp`, `rowNumber` FROM
  ( 
   SELECT l.user_id, l.timestamp, 
   IF(@lastuser_id = @lastuser_id:=user_id, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=1) rowNumber 
   FROM `log` l, (SELECT @lastuser_id:=0, @Idx:=0) A   
   ORDER BY l.user_id, l.timestamp DESC
  ) as res
  where rowNumber>3
  
 ) AS result
)